# useState not setting after refresh

Tags: reactjs, parse-server, use-state

I have an app using ReactJS and Parse Server. But the data that I'm passing on from the API is not setting after refreshing the page. Here's my code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Parse from 'parse';
const AuthContext = React.createContext({});

const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [isLoggingIn, setLoginLoading] = useState(null);
  const [loginError, setLoginError] = useState(null);
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(Parse.User.current());

  const setUserSession = currentUser => {
    setIsAuthenticated(currentUser);
    setLoginLoading(false);
    setLoginError(null);
  };

  const handleLogin = async values => {
   setLoginLoading(true);
   setLoginError(null);
   setSessionError(false);
   
   try {
      const res = await Parse.Cloud.run('login', values);
      setUser(res); // THIS IS THE DATA I WANT TO GET FROM THE API

      Parse.User.become(res.session).then(setUserSession, () => {
        setLoginError(TOKEN_VERIFY_ERROR);
        setLoginLoading(false);
      });

     setLoginLoading(false);
    } catch (e) {
      setLoginLoading(false);
      setLoginError(e.message);
    }
  };
};

return (
  <AuthContext.Provider
    value={{
      user,
      login: handleLogin,
      isLoggingIn,
      isAuthenticated,
      loginError,
    }}
  >
    {children}
  </AuthContext.Provider>
);

const AuthProvider = withRouter(AuthContextProvider);

export { AuthContext, AuthProvider };

AuthContextProvider.propTypes = {
 children: PropTypes.node,
};
```

upon logging in, user are there but when I refresh it, it returns null. What should I do to retain the details? I'm avoiding setting this to localStorage.

Comment: The state isn't cached in the browser by default. If you want to avoid local storage, you'd need to authenticate again, or refresh some kind of token/session depending how your auth system works.

Comment: Check in the debugger if you are getting the `handlelogin` when you are refreshing. It might be that cookies are set then `handlelogin` call is not trigererd.

Comment: @EmileBergeron is there a way to use useEffect for this? or should I call again the api for login where I use the AuthContext.Cosumer?

Comment: On top of the above comments, you will need an authentication check when the component mounts and set the state accordingly.

Comment: @ahmed I will check on this